# Как уменьшить размер Vue приложения

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify

интересует вопрос веса файлов при сборке Vue приложения. 
Знакомый разработчик разрабатывает на простое  React вес приложений приблизительно ~~2мб. 
Так же нашел несколько  описаний что простое Vue приложение весит в разы меньше   ~~500кб.
[image: Нормальный вес Vue app]

Вес моего приложения около ~~7мб.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подозреваю что дело в неправильной настройке webpack, однако я использовал готовую сборку webpack от Vuetify.

Comment: Что значит простое приложение??? Зависит всё от того, что вы понаимпортировали и использовали ли минификацию всех файлов. Судя по тонне js файлов маловероятно (обычно файлы склеиваются в один и из них выпиливается всё лишнее)

Comment: @Ljil, вы о чем вообще? это `lazy loading` + `source maps`

Comment: @overthesanity, а в чем может быть причина такого огромного веса source map?

Comment: в алгоритме сжатия, а вообще на продакшене они не используются, если у вас есть доступ к конфигурации вебпака, то достаточно поставить флаг `devtool: 'none'` (в продакшн билде) или использовать для таких вещей готовые плагины, они намного удобней и имеют больше возможностей, например `SourceMapDevToolPlugin`

Comment: @overthesanity, большое спасибо )

Comment: У меня большое приложение, еще и со впаяным jquery, весит < 300кб. `mode: 'production'` + `uglifyjsplugin`. Никогда не понимал людей, которые считают нормой приложение > 1мб. Сейчас таких становится просто уйма

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, Ну 1 мб это действительно в наше время ничто, а вот 7-8 мб это уже перебор..